# Prop Sent to Component is Undefined

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

i'm really stuck in this silly problem. i worked with many props but this one is a headache. maybe i'm missing something...!!!
i'm sending an object as prop from my page to a component (as i did many times!!) but on my component it's undefined!! i tried many ways (some simple data instead of obj, not bind prop, ...) but nothing!
BTW i'm on nuxt 2.13
here's my code:

page:

```
<template>
   <mycomp :err="inputError" />
<template>

<script>
import mycomp from '~/components/mycomp'
export default{
components:{
   'mycomp': mycomp
}
data(){
    return{
      inputError: {
        error: false,
        msg: null
      }
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

and my component:

```
<template>
   <div>
      {{err}} --> this show nothing too
   </div>
<template>

<script>
export default{
props:['err']
data(){
    return{
      //
    }
  },
  create(){
    console.log(this.err) // undefined
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: It's `created()`, not `create()`. And `props:['err']` is missing a `,`. Just like `components:{'mycomp': mycomp}`

Comment: Please create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue) to show the issue happening.

Comment: tanx, found out my silly mistake. i wasn't typo (just in my issue) . i had another component between this two and forgot about that!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making many typo mistakes. like  kerbh0lz mentioned. I urge you to validate the incoming props. It will save you a lot of time in debugging.

Anyway here is the working snippet

```js
//App.vue
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <HelloWorld :err="inputError"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import HelloWorld from "./components/HelloWorld";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    HelloWorld
  },
  data() {
    return {
      inputError: {
        error: false,
        msg: null
      }
    };
  }
};
</script>

//HelloWorld.vue

<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <h1>{{ err }}</h1>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  props: {
    err: {
      type: Object
    }
  },
  created() {
    console.log(this.err);
  }
};
</script>
```

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-jackson-0z3fn?https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-jackson-0z3fn?)

Comment: tanx, found out my silly mistake. i wasn't typo (just in my issue) . i had another component between this two and forgot about that!!